# Change the hour when org-mode is starting new day

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use org-mode to clock my work and sometimes I work past midnight for few hours.

So, for example, I clocked time starting 03.06.2013 10pm and ending 04.06.2013 2am.

And org-mode is dividing it at 0am, starting new day. But it would be more convinient for me if that time 0am-2am was recorded for 03.06.2013 instead of 04.06.2013.

So I want to be able to specify at what time (say, 4am) org-mode is deciding the new day has started.

I can use a workaround by shifting timezone for the emacs process, but then I need to keep in mind that all recorded time is shifted... Not very convinient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the variable `org-extend-today-until`, a variable defined in `org.el`.

> Documentation:
>   The hour when your day really ends.  Must be an integer.
>   This has influence for the following applications:
>
> - When switching the agenda to "today".  It it is still earlier than
>     the time given here, the day recognized as TODAY is actually yesterday.
> - When a date is read from the user and it is still before the time given
>     here, the current date and time will be assumed to be yesterday, 23:59.
>     Also, timestamps inserted in capture templates follow this rule.