# Specify org-mode clocktable starting time as an hour offset

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Since I often work until after midnight, I'd prefer to have the day start at 6am when tallying my total working hours.  However, I cannot figure out how to specify that time range for my clocktable.

I've tried several options, such as

`+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope file :link t :timestamp t :tstart "<-4h>"`

and

`#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope file :link t :timestamp t :tstart "<today 06:00>" :tend now`

I also tried to modify `org-extend-today-until` as mentioned in [Change the hour when org-mode is starting new day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899325/change-the-hour-when-org-mode-is-starting-new-day) but with no avail.